# React useCallback re-renders child when a click handler of parent if passed to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the parent component.

```
export default function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setNum(num + 1);
  }, [num]);

  console.log("parent renders");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Parent's num {num}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Update num</button>
      <Child handleParentClick={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And below is the child component

```
const Child = ({ handleParentClick }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };

  console.log("child renders");

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Child's counter {counter}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default memo(Child);
```

I was expecting that 'child renders' console should not be triggered when parent button is clicked. But it does console and hence child is re rendering even though I have used useCallback.

Code sandbox url: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/usecallback-clarification-5d3895?file=%2Fsrc%2FChild.js%3A11%2C1

Comment: `Child` should be memoized.

Comment: @NickParsons Already added memo. Updated the answer to accommodate that line. Also added SandBox link where the code reside.

Comment: This should not be marked as duplicate, at least not for the mentioned 'original' question. The scenarios in both the questions are difference.

Comment: It was a duplicate before your edit, as the scenarios were the same. I can't reproduce the "child renders" log when I click the "Update num" button, all I see is the "parent renders" log in your code sandbox.

Comment: @NickParsons I was updating and checking something in the Sandbox. I have reverted code to in Sandbox to reproduce the issue. Can you please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleClick` changes to a new function reference each time `num` changes as you've specified `num` as a dependency in your `useCallback` hook. So each time your click the button in your parent component, you get a new `handleClick` function which causes your `Child` to rerender. As the function reference changes, this is considered an update to the `Child`'s props, so the memoized `Child` component rerenders. If you remove the `num` dependency on the `useCallback()` hook by using the [state updater function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate) to get the current `num` state, then you will see that `Child` doesn't rerender anymore:

```js
const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
  setNum(num => num + 1);
}, []);
```

By using an empty dependency array, the `handleClick` function will only be created once on the initial mount of your parent component, and not each time `num` changes. This is safe to do here as your callback function gets `num` from the state updater function rather than the surrounding function scope, avoiding issues such as "stale state".

Comment: If I make the dependency as [], then the `num` does not increment and `parent renders` also does not get consoled.

Comment: @Murtuza Did you change it to use the state updater function like in my example code as well?

Comment: Yes, I had missed that. Adding `setNum(num => num + 1)` worked! Thanks a lot. I will read more about the state updater function.